# i cannot make it work , autcomplete from jquery ui

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

In the head section i have:

```
  script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("#auto_input").autocomplete({
        source:"../autocomplete.php",
        minLength: 5 
});
});
```

and the input where i would like to show suggestions:

```
<form action=\"../add_name.php\" method=\"get\">
b>".$NAME_INPUT.": </b>
<input name=\"auto_input\" id=\"auto_input\" class=\"input\" type=\"text\" value=\"";
                    if(isset($_GET[auto_input]))
                    {
                        $page.=$_GET['auto_input'];
                    }$page.="/>";

</form>
```

The php file which returns results contains:

```
  $string = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));
  $query = "SELECT `id`,`name` FROM `table` WHERE `name` LIKE '%".$string."%'";
  $table=$database->getTable($database->execute($query));

 for ($i = 1; $i<=$table[0];$i++){
 $row['value'] = $table[$i]['name'];
 $row['id'] = $table[$i]['id'];
 $final[] = $row;
 }
 echo json_encode($final);
```

The suggestions are not displayed, after typing 5 characters. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you verify that you PHP script a) is called and b) outputs the correct JSON string?

Comment: any errors in your console? either firebug or chrome?

Comment: you have syntax errors in all thos little snippets  not to mention the sql injection

Comment: @DaveRandom the script is called and outputs the JSON string

Comment: @DG3 i'm gonna try with firebug...

Comment: @LawrenceCherone maybe in javascript syntax i would have , i exepct you to realiza that the question contains only an example. Could you tell me more about sql injection ?

Comment: `$table[0]` Contains number of rows returned by your SQL query ?

Comment: @JBRTRND-DEV yes  it does i have printed the array in a file it looks ok.

Comment: What is "$_GET['auto_input']" ?

Comment: @JBRTRND-DEV is the value of the input when the submit button is pressed. I have tried Firebug and the answer of the header is: 302 Moved Temporarily ... Why ?

Comment: So you forgot one double quote, replace `$page.="/>";` by `$page.="\"/>";`

Comment: @JBRTRND-DEV that's not the reason.. I mean i misstyped the character ..

Comment: The value returned by php function is: [{"value":"Johnny Bravo","label":"1234"} and as an error i get undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your last comment i think that the path of source is incorrect.
The line:

```
source:"../autocomplete.php"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the error handling built in autocomplete , to determine if the json array was interpreted or not.